# ¿Cómo seleccionar el mayor valor entre una serie de columnas para subconjuntos de filas de un dataframe en R?

Tags: r, filtro, group-by

Supongamos que tengo un dataframe de 3 columnas: la primera indica el identificador de cada individuo, y las otras dos un valor correspondiente a diferentes eventos.

```
ID    <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Event1<- c(2,3,5,2,5,2,1,3,5)
Event2 <- c(1,6,2,1,2,1,2,5,6)
dataFrame <- data.frame(individuo=ID, evento1=Event1, evento2=Event2)
```

A un individuo pueden corresponderle más de una fila. ¿Es posible identificar cuál fila contiene el mayor valor, entre ambas columnas, para cada individuo?

Por ejemplo, el mayor valor para el individuo 1 se encuentra en la segunda fila, tercer columna.

Si necesitara identificar el valor basado únicamente en una única columna de valores (por ejemplo, evento1), aplicaría el siguiente código para obtener el resultado deseado:

```
Resultado_deseado <- dataFrame%>%
  group_by(individuo)%>%
  mutate(ranking = dense_rank(evento1))%>%
  filter(ranking == max(ranking))
```

Pero no me doy cuenta cómo hacer algo similar teniendo en cuenta los valores de ambas columnas.

Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo por otro lado, quizás entendí tu pregunta desde otra perspectiva, es decir, quieres identificar la fila que contenga el mayor valor, considerando mas de una columna para cada individuo, si es así, te podría servir lo siguiente:

```
dataFrame %>%
  group_by(individuo) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # crear un identificador de fila para cada individuo
  pivot_longer(cols = !c(id, individuo),
               names_to = "tipo_evento") %>% # derretir base de datos
  mutate(ranking = id[value == max(value)]) %>% #identificar la fila que contiene el mayor valor
  pivot_wider(names_from = tipo_evento,
              values_from = value) %>% # restaurar el formato de la base
  filter(id == ranking)
```

primero, con el row_number() creamos un identificador para cada fila, con el pivot_longer, creamos una variable tipo_evento que contiene los distintos eventos, ya que puedes tener muchas columnas a las cuales buscar el máximo valor.

segundo calculamos el ranking como la fila que contenga el valor maximo de los distintos eventos

finalmente volvemos al formato original de la base con el pivot_wider(), restaurando el tipo_evento a sus dos columnas en este caso en particular, ya que pueden ser mas columnas en otro caso.

Comment: Perfecto, esto es lo que necesitaba, gracias por la solución y por las explicaciones! Voy a tener en cuenta pivot_longer y pivot_wider en el futuro.